# C# Plugin Implementation Query

Tags: c#, plugins

I am trying to write a plug-in for an application. The only thing I am provided with is a dll resource file which defines an interface; here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace App.Plugin.Resources.Interface
{
  public interface IAppPlugin
  {
    string Name { get; set; }

    string Description { get; set; }

    string Author { get; set; }

    string Version { get; set; }

    Icon MenuIcon { get; set; }

    EventHandler PluginEventHandler { get; set; }
  }
}
```

I then created a class that implemented this interface, made it display a message box, compiled the dll, placed it in the Plugins folder of the application and when the application executed and launched the plugin, it did display the message.

It seems to me that the software offers the means to execute external code (through the plugin system), but doesn't actually give access to any of the application's properties or methods.

**Considering the above, my question is: Am I able to interact with the host process in any other way (e.g. get informed when a menu item is selected or even add a menu item myself to the main GUI) with the given resources or does this plugin system just act as an application launcher (by executing the code in the dll I'm providing)?**

Comment: Have you tried breakpointing in your implementation of the PluginEventHandler?  I would start here, and see if it is getting called an with what data.

Comment: What application are you plugging into?

Comment: I would ask the person that made the application you're plugging into - without telling us which application this is it is we're unlikely to know ;-)

Comment: The application is called SyMenu and it is an application launcher. The Plugin implementation system is new and the version that supports it is not even released. I got the files by emailing the developer. Thing is I want to get informed a bit before mailing him back with questions, that's why I am asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems just an application launcher, not a real plugin, unless there is some strategy implemented by convention: maybe the app looks at the plugin constructor with reflection, and pass some interfaces to the host system, or it looks for some properties marked with some custom attributes to pass some entry points.Another possible vehichle to pass the main application entry points is the `PluginEventHandler`, try to see in debug what you receive when the plugin is invoked. In addition, try to look with some tools as [ILspy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) to see if there is something more in the plugin instantiation.

Comment: After doing some more research and acting according to suggestions received here, I finally contacted the developer and confirmed that it is in fact just a code executor and nothing else. So yes, you are right, this is just an application launcher, not a real plugin. Thank you all.